# Who crucified Lilith?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

Who crucified Lilith?
As far as I remember, Adam was the first angel and landed on earth.

Lilith landed later on earth, and its Longinus Lance was destroyed or something else.

The Katsuragi Expedition discovered that Adam was impaled with the Longinus Lance and the contact experiment caused the second impact.

Since there is only one Longinus Lance (Adam's), who crucified Lilith?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewatched the series and in episode 14, Rei crucifies Lilith.