# What was Lilith during all the time?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

Followup-question to [Who crucified Lilith?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66961/who-crucified-lilith/67782#67782)

In Episode 14, Rei crucifies Lilith with the Lance of Longinus, this asks a serious question:

Lilith landed on earth billions of years ago. What was Lilith doing during all the time between that and until she is crucified? Considering Lilith is an almost god-like entity, it is weird to think that she just sits billions of years in Terminal Dogma just for a random EVA to crucify her.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that she literally just sat there for billions of years as her only purpose was to ooze out life...
Until SEELE came along and crucified her :⁠-⁠P

Just read the wiki-

> The Black Moon is the vessel that carried Lilith, one of the members of the Seeds of Life sent out into the universe by the First Ancestral Race.

I assume from the above that Lilith is a programmed artificial organism, and once it had fulfilled its role it went into a pre-programmed stasis.

Comment: but Lilith was crufied in Episode 14, where does LCL come from before that?